# Webpack-Dev-Middleware, Express and Webpack generated views. How is this suppose to work?

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-dev-middleware

- publicPath in Webpack config is set to `/contents/dist/assets/`
- a view file in Express uses `handlebars`
- in Webpack config, `handlebars` template is setup to output correct  script tags / link stylesheet..

  ```
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'views/index.handlebars',
    filename: 'views/index.handlebars',
  }),
  ```

  So this also output to `/contents/dist/assets/` under `views` folder. Thus, `/contents/dist/assets/views` is where it will be output.
- and in Express, a route is setup to serve this file.
      route.get('*', (req, res) => {
         res.render('index' .....)

And...
- I've setup `webpack-dev-middleware` to serve assets

```
  const webpack = require('webpack');
  const webpackDevMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
  const config = require('../../webpack.config');
  const compiler = webpack(config);

  const app = express();

  app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, config.devServer));
```

- I've set up a `new CleanWebpackPlugin()` plugin, to delete the contents of the `dist` folder before each build, so it start with a fresh empty folder.

**How is this suppose to actually work?**

Express is looking for the view where I've told it to look.

```
const viewsDir = resolve(__dirname, '../../client/views');
app.set('views', viewsDir);
```

When I run webpack, it delete the contents of the `dist` folder so the view is not there. BUT, isn't `webpack-dev-middleware` ***suppose*** to serve all these assets (HTML, Handlebars, etc) via memory? Not the file system? When Express hits the `/` route, there is no view to serve.

**How is all this suppose to hook together and work?**

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. I switched the project to Rails.